# Are attributes on regular methods possible

Tags: c#

Hi I'd like to put security attributes on regular instance methods. Here is an example:

```
[EnsureUserIsAdmin] //I want something like this
public IEnumerable<NameItem> GetNameItems(int Id)
{
     return _nameDataController.GetNameItems(Id);
}
```

This method is in my business logic. Any other code that uses this method will have to go through a check to see if the user is an admin. If it is possible to do this how would I unit test it?

Comment: You question is not clear. Attributes, once decorated with `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]` can be placed on any method. Attributes are just metadata about the method it is attached to.

Comment: Are you saying that `EnsureUserIsAdmin` is a custom attribute class that you've written in your business logic? Or where did that come from?

Comment: Refer this link on how to create custom attribute - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653985.aspx

Comment: Refer this link on Unit Testing C# Custom Attributes with NUnit - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/230747/Unit-Testing-Csharp-Custom-Attributes-with-NUnit

Comment: If you want to execute arbitrary code written by yourself when your method is called - you need Aspect Oriented Programming. Look here for example: https://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: I have edited the code to make it clear what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you are asking is whether you can arbitrarily restrict access to methods in an automated fashion using an attribute, then if your application's security principal object is a Windows Principal (eg. you are using Active Directory or Windows Authentication), yes you can, using the [PrincipalPermission Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "MyAdminRole")]
public void TestMethod()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter attribute unlike normal Attribute, resides on `Controller Actions` and are part of the ASP.NET controller execution process and are gathered and executed by the Routing engine.

The solution is not out of the box, and will required fair amount of non trivial complexity.
In case of non-action method you have the option of creating your own controlled environment, which will be limited and a little forced.

I would against it and use normal method preconditions or calling another validation method inside your target method to test for "security" or other validations, but certainly not attributes.

If you still want using attributes, then the following can be a solution.

You will need to make some kind of `CustomSecurityManager` which will execute the targeted method you want, he will have the responsibilities of:

1. Finding the target method
2. Collecting specific custom attributes and running them, throw exception or return false if there are issues.
3. Run the method if the attributes are valid.

**Note:** Only the CustomSecurityManager is calling the `GetNameItems`.

Unit testing can be achieved by Injecting a ICustomSecurityManager which will be mocked to return expected results.